# Removing the Proxy Icon in the bar of my mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, proxy-icon

I was wondering how to remove the proxy icon in the bar of my mac app. I've added an image so you can see what Icon I'm talking about

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://macdevelopertips.com/system/changing-an-application-icon.html - this may help you, watch the video. I have no experience with app coding but did a quick google search as I was interested but have no idea if this'll work so it is just a suggestion.

Comment: That's not really what I was looking for because this is for a mac app I'm working on and I'm going to put it on the app store in the future so I want it removed for all users and not just me. But thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 3):

The icon is included in the titlebar of the application automatically when you've created an NSDocument based application.

You can remove the proxy icon by returning `nil` from the `-[NSWindow representedURL]` method. This could be accomplished by using a custom NSWindow subclass with the method overridden; or simply setting the property to `nil` at the appropriate times.

Be aware, you might loose other functionality you normally get for free by changing this behavior, such as the dirty/clean indicator for the window, or some prompting to save when closing the window.

Alternatively, if you wanted a different image, you could use:

```
[[NSWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton] setImage:customImage]
```

Then implement `-[id<NSWindowDelegate> window:shouldPopUpDocumentPathMenu:]` to return `NO` to prevent the popup menu from appearing.

If your application isn't actually document based, or the window doesn't represent a document, consider refactoring to present this window a different way, rather than being a document window.

There is some additional information in the Cocoa [window documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SettingWindowTitle.html).